# GET call failing in AngularJS resource - Strange data result

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple angular resource that I've defined as below:

```
CompanyService.factory('CompanyService',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('https://baseurl.com/api/values/');
    }
);
```

I then have a controller that calls that resource passing in a success and fail function:

```
.controller('companyList', function($scope, CompanyService) {
$scope.companies = CompanyService.query(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("Error:");
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

The rest API is a .NET MVC Web API that is extremely basic. I've configured it to return JSON and it simply returns an array of two objects like below. I've also enabled CORS so my angular app, which is hosted in a different domain, can call the api.

```
[{ID:1, Name:"TEST1"}, {ID:2, Name:"TEST2"}]
```

I've tested the REST call using jquery and just straight call through browser. All was functional (including the cross site scripting when calling from my angular app just using a straight JavaScript HTTP call).

When I try to call the api from my controller however, it always ends up in the error function. The error object contains a data property that is always populated with the string `"resource is required|resource is required|undefined"`

When I check the network I see no call to the values end point. It's as if the call is failing before ever being made.

If I change out the url to point to some sample REST api like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/ it works fine and I'm able to see the call to "users" in the network traffic, which makes me think there is something wrong with my C# REST endpoint, however all my tests to call the REST endpoint outside of angular work successfully.

Can anyone help? I can't find anyone reporting this issues before anywhere on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding my angular app from scratch. My first app was from the angular-seed github and had a handful of libraries already added in for testing and other things. One of those things is was was leading to this error as once I started a new project completely from scratch and added in angular and my REST call things worked perfectly. I've already spent too much time working through this so not going to spend any more time identifying exactly what it is but in case anyone else runs into the problem I did want to answer this one and close the book on it.

Answer (score 0):

should the code be the one below? i didn't test it, just guess.

```
myModule.factory('CompanyService',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('https://baseurl.com/api/values/');
    }
)
.controller('companyList', function($scope, CompanyService) {
    CompanyService.query(
    function(data) {
        $scope.companies = data;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("Error:");
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi yyou, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't make a difference. Both your code and mine are valid ways of using the factory, but it never gets in to the success function. In fact, the issue I see also happens when I simply use an $http.get call. I think it might be some kind of angular setting outside my controller.